# Android Studio quit unexpectedly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My Android Studio is not opening anymore. giving me the error below:

Mac OS: OS X Yosemite version 10.10.5
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)

Error:

> Process:               studio [10945] Path:
>   /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio Identifier:
>   com.google.android.studio Version:               2.3 (AI-162.3764568)
>   Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1]
>   Responsible:           studio [10945] User ID:               502
>
> Date/Time:             2017-04-04 11:25:14.467 -0300 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F2109) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   0DEE9C1D-5244-79A6-A842-6DDC55EC3113
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       820EFB36-183A-4369-AE15-7858976DC7DA
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 17000 seconds Time Since Wake:       5600
>   seconds
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000303030353150
>
> VM Regions Near 0x303030353150:
>       VM_ALLOCATE            00000007c0260000-0000000800000000 [  1.0G] ---/rwx SM=NUL
>   --> 
>       MALLOC_TINY            00007fa3e0400000-00007fa3e0600000 [ 2048K] rw-/rwx SM=COW
>
> Application Specific Information: abort() called
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.main-thread 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x00007fff8f4b2286 __pthread_kill + 10 1   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x00007fff8a0bd9a3 abort + 129

Complete:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cs0p-3vo6xfJH7GIs6TboP0_byqMoIfUbPR3hqhlXFQ/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem upgrading the OS to Sierra.